# Como puedo mimificar javascript, css solo en produccion y no en desarrollo

Tags: javascript, css, html5, nodejs

Requiero mimificar mi código de producción(javascript, css y html), pero en el ambiente desarrollo no lo realice.

La mimificacion debe ser automatica y no manual, lo podría hacer a través de cloudflare.com pero tengo el problema que mi ambiente de desarrollo es un subdominio de producción, por ende al habilitarla opción de mimificar, lo habilitara en producción(no lo realizo por políticas de seguridad implementadas en la plataforma).

Nota:
-El backend esta echo con nodejs.

Comment: ¿Usas algún "bunlder" como webpack, grunt u otro? ¿Cómo realizas los pases a producción?

Comment: No utilizo ninguno, las subidas a producción las realizo por medio RedHat al sincronizarlo a mi repositorio de gitlab. @fredyfx

Comment: Como mencionó fredyfx podrías en principio usar un "bundler", estos bundlers generalmente generan una carpeta distínta con los archivos minimos comprimidos. Esa carpeta, sola, iría a producción, no todo el código Esa carpeta no se comitea en general, se sube aparte. Esta que te describo es una posible forma que se suele usar.

Comment: Lo eh solucionado con gulp, después de validarlo y mirar el alcance fue de gran ayuda hacerlo de esta manera para mimificarlo y ofuscarlo, de manera automatica. Gracias.